# python setup.py build_ext --inplace. no commands supplied

Tags: python, cython, anaconda, setup.py

I try to install [Starfish](https://github.com/iancze/Starfish). First I installed anaconda and the packages required, and it seems to work. (I use python 3.3 in my enviroment with the newest versions of the other packages like numpy and scipy).

I proceeded with the installation but when I do

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
I get this:
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I couldn't find any working solutions after google the problem. I tried without `--inplace` but the same result. I also tried to install `cython` without using anaconda: `sudo yum install Cython`, but still the same results.

System information:

- centOS (64bit): version 6.5
- cython -V: Cython version 0.22
- python --version: 3.3.5 :: continuum Analytics, Inc.

Test:

I am able to run the [Hello world](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) test without problems.

Any help are appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't it be `python setup.py install`?

Comment: No, some cython modules needed to be compiled. However, for some reason we got it to work, by making a cleaner install. Not sure what changed.